# Parameter pass in telerik reporting by web service data source

Tags: parameter-passing, query-string, telerik-reporting

dear all I am trying to develop a Telerik report and its data source is web service data source.
I complete all process according to Telerik reporting instruction and it can access my service initially. and pass parameter value as well as but when I click finish but to complete adding by data model it again hit my backend and pass parameters name not value.

please help me out from this trouble. it already kill my day.
for more reference please see the attached image.
[image]
Initiation step 1:

[image]
parameter assign:

[image]
Backend receive parameter when i press download button correctly.

[image]

according to parameter retrieve data:
[image]
But finally when click finish button it hit again in backend and backend receive the parameter value like this. and this is the main problem.

I hope I can explain. please help me from this trouble.

Comment: Could you further explain what the problem is? Are you getting an error?

Comment: when I click the finish button, it hit again in controller and pass parameter value  "=Parameters.rptfromDate.Value". but when I click  download  download button, it pass  parameter value like "2022-01-01"